# Python fucntions , how I should started the programming

Tags: python, function, web, concept, priority-web-sdk

So, I have question about the functions of python. Should I learn all combinations , for example math function in order to be a Junior programmer. Then for django developer must know how to work with algorithms and subsequence. Also last question what should I begin with if I want to be a python developer.

I tried so many things like creating the telegram bots through the python because It is seemed to me easy. I have also learned from beginning untill module.

Comment: Please read [what topics can I ask about here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). This question does not fit here on stackoverflow

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Unfortunately this question is not an acceptable question here. As a new user, you should read [ask] to know the kind of question that is expected on this site. That being said, you should start with tutorials. A number of them are referenced in the official Python documentation. The nice point in tutos, is that they will take you from the beginning and add new *tools* one at a time. For Django, my advice is not to go that way until you are rather proficient in Python. As Django is a Python framework it supposes an acceptable knowledge in Python. Go one step at a time

Comment: If it was me, I would start by looking and questions related to data manipulation here on SO and pick one that does not look too hard and try to generate an answer. If you are not quite there yet then I would do a search for "simple python programming exercises" and see if that gave you something to sink your teeth into.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my opinion, the best way to learn a programming language is learning first how programming languages work and programming generic concepts: You will see that the concepts that apply into a certain programming language are usually concepts that can be applied to other languages. This is because programming language are just a tool to explain to a computer what to do. You can explain the same thing to a computer with totally diferent words. But even if the words are different, meaning of those words remain the same.

So, this means that if you want to learn Django, you are probably into web development. So, if you want to learn Python + Django, I would suggest that you learn how the basic components of web work. Those basic concepts will make you understand the idea (specification) behind a certain programming concept or technology and with this knowledge you will be able to write code in any language that fulfills that specification (implementation).

So, regarding your question, I do not think that you should know how to use all the math functions in Python, but at least **know** that they exist. You should be able to know that there are functions to compute logarithms, square roots, etc. And that you do not need to implement them from scratch. Nowadays, doing generic stuff with any programming language is super easy with Google or chatGPT, so if you need to implement a very specific mathematical function, there is probably someone out there that programmed it before.

That does not mean that I recommend that you abuse Python library without understanding what is going on, but instead you should implement small examples to get familiarized with the concepts that you are *borrowing* from other's people code. For example, as a developer, I rarely write code to sort a data structure. Usually there is a library function that does it for you. But if that library function is not working anymore or it does not exactly what I need, I can implement my own function. Maybe my code will not be as optimized as the one in the library, but because I know how to sort a list and I know the Python syntax I would be able to tell the computer how to sort a data structure in Python. So, yeah, we developers are nothing more than mere translators from natural language to a formal language like a programming language.

On the other hand, answering to your other question:

> Also last question what should I begin with if I want to be a python
> developer.

If you want to become a Python developer you should practice your coding skills in Python as much as you can. In the beginning it does not matter very much what do you program since you will be learning basic stuff. I actually recommend that you take a Python course to learn its syntax and features. You can find a lot of free online options on the Internet. There are lots of coding competitions and problems where you can test your level. In my opinion, [this is a good one since it has problems of different level](https://leetcode.com/).

After you learn the basic concepts of python and have implemented some projects I recommend that you specialize in the type of development that you want to do. So if you are into web development start learning web concepts and start doing web applications.

Also, if you want to be a developer (does not matter the programming language) you **MUST** learn git. I recommend that you create a gitlab or github account.

Comment: Thank you for your advise , No I know what I should do . Then I think that I am not sure , the beginners for this profession have  to start with leetcode , the reason is that Leetcode contatins a complicated concepts of any languages.